# set property from running thread to ViewModel in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm beginner in Caliburn.Micro so if something is not clear or this implementation is wrong, please let me know. I have a `DataGridViewModel` with properties `Name`, `Data`

```
class DataGridViewModel : Screen
{
    private char name;

    public char Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
        }
    }

    private DataTable data;
    public DataTable Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Data);
        }
    }
}
```

and a `MainViewModel` with properties `Fitness` and `GenerationCout`. In a `MainView` is a button which starts a new thread of my `Genetic` class.

```
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.AllActive
{
    private Genetic genetic;

    private double fitness;
    public double Fitness
    {
        get { return fitness; }
        set
        {
            fitness = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Fitness);
        }
    }

    private int generationCout;
    public int GenerationCout
    {
        get { return generationCout; }
        set
        {
            generationCout = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => GenerationCout);
        }
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        List<string> features = new List<string> { "(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)" };
        genetic = new Genetic(features);
        genetic.Start();
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        generationCout = 0;
        fitness = 0;
    }

}
```

There are fields like `best` and `generationCount`. And there is a method `SetActual()` which is using in running thread of this class. In the method I'm setting actual fields value and I want to sent it to ViewModels eventually refresh it in Views.

```
public class Genetic : BaseThread
{
    private int generationCount;
    private Subject best;

    private void SetActual()
    {
        DataTable data;
        char name;
        double fitness;
        foreach (Operation operation in best.Operations)
        {
            DataTable data;
            data = Converter.ArrayToDataTable(operation);
            name = operation.Name;
            fitness = best.Fitness;
        }
        generationCount++;
    }
}
```

So I need show an actual value of those fields in my views during thread is running. Can anyone tell me how to do that with use the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily notify Genetic's properties change from Genetic class itself by extend `PropertyChangedBase` and expose it directly from your ViewModel then refer to `Genetic` class property on `MainViweModel` from control

```
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.AllActive
{
    private Genetic genetic;

    public Genetic CurrentGenetic
    {
        get { return genetic; }
        set
        {
            genetic = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CurrentGenetic));
        }
    }
}
public class Genetic : PropertyChangedBase 
{
    private int generationCount;

    public int GenerationCout
    {
        get { return generationCount; }
        set
        {
            generationCount = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CurrentGenetic));
        }
    }
 }

 // example binding
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentGenetic.GenerationCout }" />
 // or caliburn micro convention
 <TextBlock x:Name="CurrentGenetic_GenerationCout" />
```

if you don't want to extend `PropertyChangedBase`, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChangedEx`(caliburn micro versioin of `INotifyPropertyChanged`) as https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/PropertyChangedBase.cs

more about Conventions see [All about Conventions](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/conventions)

Comment: Thank you, it's very useful! And I'm sorry I reply late.